# Unable to use the laravel whereTime() filter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter query results by time on my table's timestamp column. I've had no issues with whereDate() but when I try the following

```
    $users = DB::table('users')->whereTime('created_at', '=', '11:20:45')->get();
```

(which I even took from laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) page) I get the following error:

[image]

(Sorry if It's in spanish, basically it complains that the syntax is incorrect)

Comment: What DBMS are you using here?

Comment: @Devon PostgreSQL. the column format is '2018-07-09 09:30:10'

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgres, does `SELECT extract(time from "created_at") FROM "users"` work directly in postgres?

Comment: @MathewMagante I have return json_encode($users); right after but it doesnt reach it. Neither dd($users);

Comment: @Devon hm it does not, I get the same syntax error. I guess the problem could be related to the DBMS

Comment: Seems like a bug in the postgres implementation of whereTime then.  You may want to report an issue on laravel's github.   I think postgres users are a small minority of laravel users.   Do you know the correct syntax of pulling a time from a datetime field in postgres?

Comment: I am using SQL server and try whereTime but it also not working for me. I up vote this question.

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I'm running version 5.4. How stupid of me! whereTime is only supported by version 5.5+ and above. I will retry after upgrading the version and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching my project's laravel version from 5.4 to 5.5 fixed the issue